# Java Embedded Database to Standalone Database

Tags: java, database, h2

Im workings on java project.its a desktop application (financial application).

I want to when user in offline save all data in embedded database (H2 database) and when user come to online or click on some button save all the new data on Standalone database(My SQL server) server.
Right now i kindda lost with this scenario.
Can some one describe how this should be done or is this possible.

Comment: Just want to understand, like what do you mean by offline. Is it like your backend server is down or your Database service is down. Can you please elaborate it further to answer your question precisely ?

Comment: This is not a web app.this is PC application.so offline mean   ,user not connect to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

**Based on Assumption as your question seem to pointing below requirement,**

1. you have local H2 database
2. mysql may be on other network.
3. If you save some data on application then goes to h2 database
4. one you connected to internet the data should go to mysql database which is on differnet host from h2 local database where application is running.

**Solution :**

you need to add replication tools which replicate data from one database to another seemlessly.

Refer One of the nice tool : https://www.symmetricds.org/

Let me know if you have any other requirement. Also please provide enough details when raising the questions. Thanks.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant but h2 database not server base database it's a embedded database (just like sqlite)

Comment: Thats true. Have done replication of sqlite to sqlite in one of the project.Refer databases supported by symmetricds : https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.0/html/databases.html

Comment: No i haven't used it

Answer (score 0):

Replicating data from H2 DB to Mysql DB using a replicator tool is one way.

Other way to achieve the same is rather than creating a heavy in-memory DB instance on client machine is you can write the same data in file on client machine at some location and write a scheduler program which will check the heart beat of socket and if ping to your server is successful you can read file and upload the data to your actual DB server. Also Writing your own scheduler and data uploader will give you more control.

Other issue with any replicator tool is data type compatibility.

Still if you want to go ahead with any replication tool- you can have a look at Tungsten Replicator - https://docs.continuent.com/tungsten-replicator-4.0/deployment-oracle-fromoracle.html